# Check if an expression involving quantifiers is a tautology

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Check if an expression:
$$\forall_x(\Phi(x) \Rightarrow \forall_x \Psi(x)) \Rightarrow \forall_x (\Phi(x) \Rightarrow \Psi(x))$$
is a tautology. I've tried many different approaches, and every one failed. I think that my best attempt so far was  this: Notice that if the LHS is false, then no matter what RHS is, the statement will be true. However, if LHS is true, then RHS must also be true in order for the statement to be true. Indeed, *let's assume that the LHS is true*. Now, what can we say about $\forall_x \Psi(x)$? It's a constant (call it $c$), because $x$ is bound by the quantifier. There are two possibilities:

1. $c$ is true
   Then $\Phi(x)$ can be either true or false, it doesn't matter, LHS will be true anyway. So RHS is true because for all $x$ we get a true statement (remember, $\Psi(x)$ is true *for all x*).
2. $c$ is false
   Then $\Phi(x)$ must be also false for all $x$. But then, no matter if $\Psi$ is right or false, RHS is true.
   So it makes it look like a tautology, but it is not. My textbook even gives a counter-example. I have no idea at which point I am wrong here... I would be grateful if you could provide me with some method on how to deal with such problems (determining if an expression involving quantifiers is true or false).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with your reasoning.

The only way that this is not a tautology is if the LHS is true and the RHS is false.

If the RHS is false, that means $\exists_x \Phi(x) \land \lnot \Psi(x)$. Let's call that value of $x$ "$\alpha$".

If the LHS is to be true, it must also hold for both $x$'s to be equal to $\alpha$. And indeed, that would lead to a contradiction.

Could you provide us with the counterexample from your textbook?

Comment: $\Phi(x): 2|x$ and $\Psi(x): 3|x$

Comment: Yeah, I don't see how that is a counterexample ...

Comment: Frankly, I don't see either... It seems like I found a mistake in the textbook. Thanks a lot for answering my question! I thought I was going nuts